# extracting JSON data in Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart, parsing

I'm trying to render a list of elements in Flutter and the list data is coming from a REST API.

I cant seem to find an example that will allow me to extract parameter

> frm_payload

from the following JSON output. The messages reoccur and I would like to end up with a list of strings displaying the value for this field, which in the following example would be:

> T1BF

```
{
"result": {
    "end_device_ids": {
        "device_id": "unitx1",
        "application_ids": {
            "application_id": "jandraapp"
        },
        "dev_eui": "A8A55920F540DBDF",
        "dev_addr": "260BC823"
    },
    "received_at": "2021-07-12T18:28:33.504479658Z",
    "uplink_message": {
        "f_port": 1,
        "f_cnt": 5,
        "frm_payload": "T1BF",
        "rx_metadata": [
            {
                "gateway_ids": {
                    "gateway_id": "packetbroker"
                },
                "packet_broker": {
                    "message_id": "01FADZMPC8E58VRNYC5WWQRRFS",
                    "forwarder_net_id": "000013",
                    "forwarder_tenant_id": "ttnv2",
                    "forwarder_cluster_id": "ttn-v2-eu-1",
                    "forwarder_gateway_eui": "58A0CBFFFE803615",
                    "forwarder_gateway_id": "eui-58a0cbfffe803615",
                    "home_network_net_id": "000013",
                    "home_network_tenant_id": "ttn",
                    "home_network_cluster_id": "ttn-eu1"
                },
                "time": "2021-07-12T18:28:33.277776956Z",
                "rssi": -90,
                "channel_rssi": -90,
                "snr": 7.75
            }
        ],
        "settings": {
            "data_rate": {
                "lora": {
                    "bandwidth": 125000,
                    "spreading_factor": 7
                }
            },
            "data_rate_index": 5,
            "coding_rate": "4/5",
            "frequency": "867500000"
        },
        "received_at": "2021-07-12T18:28:33.295783006Z",
        "consumed_airtime": "0.051456s"
    }
}
```

}

Here is how I am calling it from my dart code, where

> post

is the decoded JSON object

"frm_payload: ${post["result"]["uplink_message"]["frm_payload"]}"

Here is the full code that I have in flutter:

```
    import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

/// This is the main application widget.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: MyStatefulWidget(),
    );
  }
}

/// This is the stateful widget that the main application instantiates.
class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

/// This is the private State class that goes with MyStatefulWidget.
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  static const TextStyle optionStyle =
      TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);
  static const List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    Text(
      'Index 0: Homexx',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 1: Business',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 2: School',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 3: Settings',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
  ];

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  final url =
      "https://eu1.cloud.thethings.network/api/v3/as/applications/jandraapp/devices/unitx1/packages/storage/uplink_message";
  // final url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";

  var _postsJson = [];

  void fetchPosts() async {
    print('FETCHPOSTS_PRETRY');
    try {
      final response = await get(Uri.parse(url));
      final jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body) as List;

      setState(() {
        _postsJson = jsonData;

        print('FETCHPOSTS');
      });
    } catch (err) {
      print(' FORMATTING ERROR');
    }
  }

  

    @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        fetchPosts();
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        print(_postsJson.length);
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('Device Status Screen'),
          ),
          body: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: _postsJson.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, i) {
              final post = _postsJson[i];
    
              return Text(
                  "frm_payload: ${post["result"]["uplink_message"]["frm_payload"]}"); // ***** THIS IS THE PROBLEM CODE*******
    
              // return Text("Title: ${post["title"]}\n Body: ${post["body"]}\n\n");
            },
          ),
          bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
            items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                label: 'Home',
                backgroundColor: Colors.red,
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.history),
                label: 'History',
                backgroundColor: Colors.green,
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
                label: 'Settings',
                backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
              ),
            ],
            currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
            selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
            onTap: _onItemTapped,
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where's the problem - this works in dartpad.dev:

```
void main() {
  const post=<String, dynamic>{
"result": {
    "end_device_ids": {
        "device_id": "unitx1",
        "application_ids": {
            "application_id": "jandraapp"
        },
        "dev_eui": "A8A55920F540DBDF",
        "dev_addr": "260BC823"
    },
    "received_at": "2021-07-12T18:28:33.504479658Z",
    "uplink_message": {
        "f_port": 1,
        "f_cnt": 5,
        "frm_payload": "T1BF",
        "rx_metadata": [
            {
                "gateway_ids": {
                    "gateway_id": "packetbroker"
                },
                "packet_broker": {
                    "message_id": "01FADZMPC8E58VRNYC5WWQRRFS",
                    "forwarder_net_id": "000013",
                    "forwarder_tenant_id": "ttnv2",
                    "forwarder_cluster_id": "ttn-v2-eu-1",
                    "forwarder_gateway_eui": "58A0CBFFFE803615",
                    "forwarder_gateway_id": "eui-58a0cbfffe803615",
                    "home_network_net_id": "000013",
                    "home_network_tenant_id": "ttn",
                    "home_network_cluster_id": "ttn-eu1"
                },
                "time": "2021-07-12T18:28:33.277776956Z",
                "rssi": -90,
                "channel_rssi": -90,
                "snr": 7.75
            }
        ],
        "settings": {
            "data_rate": {
                "lora": {
                    "bandwidth": 125000,
                    "spreading_factor": 7
                }
            },
            "data_rate_index": 5,
            "coding_rate": "4/5",
            "frequency": "867500000"
        },
        "received_at": "2021-07-12T18:28:33.295783006Z",
        "consumed_airtime": "0.051456s"
    }
}};
  
  print("frm_payload: ${post["result"]["uplink_message"]["frm_payload"]}");
}
```

Comment: thank you very much indeed. Yes I can also get to work in dart dev like you. I have added my complete code from Flutter. Maybe its something esle I am doing wrong? in the example I always Get "FORMATTING ERROR"as I have created a try catch condition for this.

Comment: I think you are not decoding it in the right way. Just replace ````final jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body) as List;```` with ````final jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body);````. You don't have to convert it to list - since the parsed object is Map<String, dynamic>.

Comment: oh wow thank you! I am now getting: Error: Expected a value of type 'List<dynamic>', but got one of type '_JsonMap' - is it the widget that is causing this error? ifso how do I get a list of frm_payload in a dropdown list?

Comment: It looks like its an authentication problem. Because I am accessing the JSON string from my machine, it is not showing a problem. I have the option of getting API key, OAuth access token or a Session cookie. which one should I use and how?